close account cause token lost?
Say I have an token address, it contains some usdt.
If I close the token address, by withdraw all sol.
Will the usdt (and any other tokens) in that address lost ?
If it's lost, is there any way to get the usdt back ?

The token program doesn't allow you to close accounts if they have a balance. If that were possible, then it would be possible to burn tokens without correctly updating the supply of the token.
Here's the check in the source code: https://github.com/solana-program/token/blob/62ff9d3ca0651b245ec281af68bd50302bff84b8/program/src/processor.rs#L684

In my test, I must transfer token out by hand, to make its amount = 0, then call token's CloseAccount instruction, to close the account. If I left the amount > 0, calling CloseAccount instruction, will get a sig = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111, that's fail I think. Can u confirm this behaviour is what you mean in the answer ?

The signature has nothing to do with the success or failure of the transaction. that just means that an expected signature is missing, since 111... is just all zero in base-58 encoding. You might need to provide the code that you're running and the full error that you're seeing

I got it, there is an error in the simulation, I forgot to check the error, the signature is just 0000.., when convert to base58, it become 11..
